# Assign Color and Texture both as material to Polygon in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I am using `Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty` which provides option to set image and color as material.
I am adding material to polygon, assigning it a transparent image and a color. but it is only showing the image ignoring the color (image attached).
Any suggestion on how we can set both image and color as material to polygon.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create the Cesium.Material for the polygon
var material = new Cesium.Material({
    fabric: {
        type: 'Image',
        uniforms: {
            image: 'path/to/transparent/image.png',
            color: Cesium.Color.RED
        },
        source: `
            czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput)
            {
                czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput);
                vec2 st = materialInput.st;
                vec4 imageColor = texture2D(image, vec2(st.s, 1.0 - st.t));
                material.diffuse = imageColor.rgb * color.rgb;
                return material;
            }
        `
    }
});

// Create your polygon entity
var polygon = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
            -115.0, 37.0,
            -115.0, 32.0,
            -107.0, 33.0,
            -102.0, 31.0,
            -102.0, 35.0
        ]),
        material: material
    }
});
```

Comment: can't find ```CompositeMaterialType``` in cesiium

Comment: Updated code. Try that.

Comment: getting error, 
message
: 
"fabric: cannot have source and components in the same template."
name
: 
"DeveloperError"